# File.getCanonicalPath() returns error if directory begins with a dot

Tags: java, file

**Note:** Invalid question, issue was caused by a misplaced `!` in a parent function. The question is flagged so it can be removed by a moderator.

---

I've created a function that checks if a (file/directory) path is valid without checking if it exists;

```
public static boolean isValidPath(String path) {
    File f = new File(path);
    try {
        f.getCanonicalPath();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `File.getCanonicalPath();` returns an error when any of the directories begins with a dot, altough it's a valid directory path for Windows. This causes the function to return `false` which should be `true`.
For example the path `C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin` returns `false` whereas `C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\minecraft\bin` without the dot on the minecraft directory returns `true`. The first path with the dot in the directory name does exist on my system and I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. Is there any other function to check if a path is valid, or what else could I do to fix this issue?

Comment: What kind of error do you see? Could you send the stacktrace?

Comment: Are you saying if `path` is `C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\minecraft\bin`, then `f.getCanonicalPath()` works correctly?

Comment: *"Thanks in advance,
Tim Visée"*  Don't include noise in questions.  My results seem to contradict your statements.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry, it seems to be caused by a parent method. It's seems to be caused by .isFile() when checking if a file inside a directory beginning with a dot is valid. Altough, when I remove the dot it works fine. I'll flag my question and ask to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;

class TestDirWithDot {

    public static boolean isValidPath(String path) {
        File f = new File(path);
        try {
            f.getCanonicalPath();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
        String path = ".dir";
        System.out.println(isValidPath(path));
    }
}
```

---

```
Windows Vista
true
```

Comment: Same on `Linux` (Ubuntu 12.04, OpenJDK).

Answer (score 0):

> The first path with the dot in the directory name does exist on my
>   system and I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.

So you will get

`IOException` - If an I/O error occurs, which is possible because the construction of the canonical pathname may require filesystem queries.

> Is there any other function to check if a path is valid ?
>   Try this:

```
File file = new File("c:\fileName");
if (!file.isDirectory())
   file = file.getParentFile();
if (file.exists()){
    ...
}
```